# Copy from one text file to another if text begins and ends with

Tags: python

I'm new to this so be gentle. So I am trying to copy a string of text that begins with GA and ends in GB and begins from GC and GD from and one test file to another using python. So transfer "GA have a good day GB" and "GC have a better day GD" from text file Text1 to Text2. Only what's in between and nothing else before of after. Please help. Thanks

```
with open('Test1.txt') as infile, open('Test2.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "GA":
            copy = True
        if copy:
            outfile.write(line)
        # move this AFTER the "if copy"
        if line.strip() == "GB":
            copy = False
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I would suggest first understand strings in python and file handling in python. Once you know how to read files, search for substrings in strings, write to files, etc, try combining these to solve your problem. And if you're still not able to, post your code and errors and let people help you.

Comment: Can you try to write a solution and see what errors you get? If you can get past the errors, good. If not, post the code and the errors here. Good luck!

Comment: Look up these items:  `str.startswith()`, `str.endswith()`, `str.find()`, string slicing, and the `in` statement.

Comment: Can you also include some of the text the text files contain? As thats always helpful when working with contents of files

Answer (score 1):

There are functions that test start and end of strings: [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and [`endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith).
So it boils down to no more than this:

```
with open('Test1.txt') as infile, open('Test2.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith("GA") and line.endswith("GB") or line.startswith("GC") and line.endswith("GD"):
            outfile.write(line)
```